# create a method where the variable is a jTable

Tags: java, methods, jtable

I have 3 different buttons on java, depending on with I press I want to take a value from one of 3 different Tables I have so:

```
public MethodName (String Table) {
    String value=Table.getValueAt(1,1);
   Return value;
}
```

how can this be done so Table is substitute with `jTable1`, `jTable2`, or `jTable3`?
is this possible?

Comment: you have to pass `JTable` object to `MethodName` method not a `String` and "Return" should be `return` since java is case sensitive.

Comment: great Just Worked thanks :)